# System.AccessViolationException: in WCF Application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, model-view-controller

i got System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. error and my code is

```cs
 private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var button = (Button)sender;
                String[] name = button.Name.Split('_');
                string Cameraid = name[1];

                if (Convert.ToInt32(Cameraid) <= 99)
                {
                    Cameraid = (string)button.Tag;
                    Cameraid= Cameraid.Split('_')[1];
                }

                if (devices_hist.ContainsKey(Cameraid))
                {
                    string devicename = devices_hist[Cameraid].agent_devicename;
                    string vlcstream = devices_hist[Cameraid].vlcstream;
                    int counter = Convert.ToInt32(name[2]);
                    if (mps[counter] != null)
                        mps[counter].Dispose();
                   
                    if (vlcstream != "0")
                    {
                        // Release the existing media
                        medias[counter]?.Dispose();

                        LibVLC VLC=new LibVLC();

                        // Create a new media with the updated VLC stream source
                        medias[counter] = new Media(VLC, vlcstream, LibVLCSharp.Shared.FromType.FromLocation);

                        // Update the MediaPlayer with the new media
                        mps[counter].Media = medias[counter];
                        mps[counter].Play();

                    }
                    //
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                clsLog.logFiles(ex.StackTrace + " Exception : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

i want to know the exact resolution

Comment: From the code you provided alone, I don't see the use of the WCF client and the invocation of methods. At the same time, I think the problem is caused by you accessing the memory that is disposed. I recommend that you debug the code and see which line the problem is, so that it is easier to confirm the problem.